# How to delete different updatable records in one shot?

Tags: java, sql, list, collections, jooq

How to delete List of **different tablerecords** from a single query in JOOQ? Is this possible with JOOQ API? Or i have to delete record one by one ,Just get one record fire query and so on?

For Ex:
I have two records of different tables Like :

**MyTableRecord1** and **MyTableRecord2**

I want to delete List of records from these two tables in a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [`DSLContext.batchDelete()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .batchDelete(record1, record2)
   .execute();
```

It'll generate JDBC batch statements for "similar" delete statements. If you're deleting from two tables, one record each, this will just generate two different delete statements.